# How to retrieve all MySQL settings?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a configured MySQL server (MySQL 5.1.47-community) that works perfect. I installed a second server (MySQL 5.5.15-community) to see if the new version of MySQL would work with my application before upgrading.

When I run the application against the new server it behaves different. When I run it against the old server (MySQL 5.1.47-community) everything works perfect.

I remember that I set some parameters through the MySQL prompt to accept larger result set and some other stuff, now I can't remember what I did.

So my question is: Is there a way to transfer all the MySQL settings from one server to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL settings are stored in your my.cnf (or my.ini) file.

To transfer your original settings from one server to another, it's usually a simple matter of copying the original settings file to the new server.

For your reference, here is a link to section [4.2.3.3. Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) from the MySQL 5.5 Manual.

Hope that helps!

Comment: When I copy the my.ini file to the new server it refuses to start. I have double checked all paths and nothings seems to be wrong there. Obviously there are some new stuff in the newer version. I did complain about "default-characterset" so I removed it, but still no difference.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is your original server running? You will need to update any directives in your `my.cnf` to match your new servers' MySQL 5.5.